# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CamelContext must be specified on: Message[] - Camel core

Tags: maven, apache-camel, camel-core

Below is builder from camel core & writting junit testcases with it & camel core version used is 2.22.1.

```
new ExchangeBuilder(null)
      .withBody(body)
      .withHeader(header, headerValue)
      .build();
```

Junit testcases is throwing error when calling above builder - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CamelContext must be specified on: Message[]

Comment: What is it specifically that you want an answer for?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to provide constructor of `ExchangeBuilder` a instance of CamelContext. If your test class inherits from CamelTestBuilder you can use `context()` method to obtain it during a test.

```java
public class SomeTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    
    @Test
    public void testSomething(){

        String body = "some body";
        String header = "SomeHeader";
        String headerValue = "Some header value";

        ExchangeBuilder builder = new ExchangeBuilder(context())
            .withBody(body).withHeader(header, headerValue);
        
        Exchange exchange = builder.build();
        CamelContext contextFromExchange = exchange.getContext();
        // Do something with the exchange?
    }
}
```

If you're not using one of the [camel-test modules](https://camel.apache.org/manual/testing.html#_testing_modules) you'll have to create and configure one manually using e.g `new DefaultCamelContext();`. For testing routes use of one of the camel-test modules is highly recommended though as they make things a lot easier.